# Execute simple UPDATE sql statement with 2 tables and QueryBuilder

Tags: typo3

I've got a simple SQL statement which should be used in TYPO3 in order to migrate data:

```
update table1 as t1,table2 as t2 set t1.field1=t2.field2 where t1.uid=t2.uid;
```

As you can see, there is no user input, nothing needs to be quoted.

Using TYPO3 QueryBuilder what you can do is a JOIN, but I did not get it to work with UPDATE.

```
$queryBuilder = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class)
    ->getQueryBuilderForTable('table1');

$queryBuilder->update('table1')
   ->join(
       'table1', 
       'table2', 
       't2',
       $queryBuilder->expr()->eq(
           't2.uid', 
           $queryBuilder->quoteIdentifier('table1.uid')
       )
   )
   ->set(
       'table1.field1', 
       $queryBuilder->quoteIdentifier(
           't2.field2'
       ), 
       false
   )->execute();
```

*"An exception occurred while executing 'UPDATE `table1` SET `table1`.`field1` = `t2`.`field2`': Unknown column 't2.field2' in 'field list'"*

**Update:**

$queryBuilder->getSQL() returns:

```
UPDATE `table1` SET `table1`.`field1` = `t2`.`field2`
```

Ok, so the join was not applied. I only found examples for SELECT + JOIN in the docs.

Comment: Can you please reformat your code? It's rather hard to see what starts and ends where. Did you use `$queryBuilder->getSQL()` to check the result before executing?

Comment: @Mathias Thank you for your hints, I updated my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The offical TYPO3 docs state:

> Calls on join() methods are only considered for ->select() and
>   ->count() type queries. ->delete(), ->insert() and update() do not support joins, those query parts are ignored and do not end up in the
>   final statement.
>
> https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/Database/QueryBuilder/Index.html#join-innerjoin-rightjoin-and-leftjoin

This is a limitation imposed by [Doctrine DBAL](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/issues/2716).

You can use executeQuery or preferably executeUpdate of the Doctrine connection object to execute raw querys. Not tested example, but something like this should work.:

```
$updateQuery = "UPDATE table1
                SET $connection->quoteIdentifier('table1.field1') = $connection->quoteIdentifier('table2.field2')
                WHERE $connection->quoteIdentifier('table1.uid') = $connection->quoteIdentifier('table2.uid')"; 
$connection->executeQuery($updateQuery);
```

Comment: Works with your query, slightly modified: 'UPDATE table1, table2 SET ' . $connection->quoteIdentifier('table1.field1') . ' = ' . $connection->quoteIdentifier('table2.field2') . ' WHERE ' . $connection->quoteIdentifier('table1.uid')  . ' = ' . $connection->quoteIdentifier('table2.uid');